# datatable and jquery doesn't working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Guys I'm driving crazy with this code:
I'm trying to populate my datagrid with the datatable plugin but I'm not understanding why it doesn't working. I have a message whith:

> DataTables warning: table id=item_data - Invalid JSON response.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item_data').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url:"item_fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[7, 8, 9],
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ],
        "pageLength": 10 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<table id="item_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>                                
      <th>Item Code</th>
      <th>Item Description</th>
      <th>Product Line</th>                                 
      <th>Purchase Standard Cost</th>
      <th>Last Receipt</th>                                 
      <th>Status</th>                                   
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>                          
  <?php //include("item_list.php"); ?>                          
</table>
```

Theoretically item_fetch execute the query to populate my datagrid but, the java code doesn't reading the table id.
Above my item_fetch code

```php
<?php

//item_fetch.php

include('phpfunc/database_connection.php');
include('phpfunc/function.php');

$query = '';

$output = array();
$query .= "
    SELECT * FROM item 
    INNER JOIN i_prodline ON i_prodline,prodline_id = item.item_prodline
";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE i_prodline.prodline_cod LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR i_prodline.prodline_desc LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR item.item_code LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR item.item_desc LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';  
}

if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY item_code DESC ';
}

if($_POST['length'] != -1)
{
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $status = '';
    if($row['item_status'] == 'active')
    {
        $status = '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        $status = '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';
    }
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_code'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_desc'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['prodline_cod'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_standardcost'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_datareceipt'];    
    $sub_array[] = $status;
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="view" id="'.$row["item_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view">View</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["item_id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["item_id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-status="'.$row["item_status"].'">Delete</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_total_all_records($connect)
{
    $statement = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM item');
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records($connect),
    "data"              =>  $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Please how can I fix it? I'm not understanding where is the mistake.

Comment: Do you have the `echo $query;` in your live code? Because in that case your JSON is appended to that echo and therefor it's invalid JSON.

Comment: live code means here? I'm sorry for my stupid question..

Comment: The actual code that gives you this error. This is not some debugging leftover that was not in the code when you got that error?

Comment: This is the my actual code, java and html code are in the same page and then I have item_fetch.php .... The difference is that script src is in a differente page.

Comment: Try to remove the `echo $query;` from your php and see if it works.

Comment: No it still doesn't working...

Comment: Is: "ON i_prodline,prodline_id" right? Theres a "," between  i_prodline and prodline_id. Shouldnt it be a "." (dot)?

Comment: As @Celebrombore stated, i think this is a misstype error. Anyway i am trying to let Fabio debug this php code.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: draw in ...php on line 77
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[["SVSWS5858381414NL","5\/8 Comp*3\/8comp*1\/4comp(1\/4\") angle speedy vlv LF","BLKF","1.561","2018-04-10 00:00:00","Inactive<\/span>","View<\/button>","Update<\/button>","Delete<\/button>"],["CIP3","3 CAST IRON PIPE 10'","BLKF","27.95","2018-04-10 00:00:00","Inactive<\/span>","View<\/button>","Update<\/button>","Delete<\/button>"],["BV12IPSLB","L\/P 1\/2 IPS BALL VALVE","PVCF","5.77","2018-04-12 00:00:00","Inactive<\/span>","View<\/button>","Update<\/button>","Delete<\/button>"]]}

Comment: @Celebrombore is a misstype error... I fixed it, thanks

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you left some debugging echo in your php code that is producing invalid JSON (thus the message from Datatable API).

Please comment line 32 in your php code.
Here is how it should look like later:

```
<?php
//item_fetch.php

include('phpfunc/database_connection.php');
include('phpfunc/function.php');

$query = '';

$output = array();
$query .= "
    SELECT * FROM item 
    INNER JOIN i_prodline ON i_prodline,prodline_id = item.item_prodline
";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE i_prodline.prodline_cod LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR i_prodline.prodline_desc LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR item.item_code LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR item.item_desc LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';  
}

if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY item_code DESC ';
}
//forgot to comment out debug echos
//echo $query;
if($_POST['length'] != -1)
{
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $status = '';
    if($row['item_status'] == 'active')
    {
        $status = '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        $status = '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';
    }
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_code'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_desc'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['prodline_cod'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_standardcost'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['item_datareceipt'];    
    $sub_array[] = $status;
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="view" id="'.$row["item_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view">View</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["item_id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["item_id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-status="'.$row["item_status"].'">Delete</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_total_all_records($connect)
{
    $statement = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM item');
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records($connect),
    "data"              =>  $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Comment: @Fabio Please post your php code output (json) after code update.
Please post also if there is any error/warning from datatables API in your console - probably it has changed.

Comment: I don't have response from this code and if I try to copy this code in a nwe project I have a empty table and no errors... I'm really confused

Comment: Please add those lines at the start of your php script.
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
This way your script will show errors.
Please check php output again.

Comment: If you are checking your php output you can't see any javascript error (it's not java). Please find a way to directly query you php script and post it's output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169448/discussion-between-giacomo-penuti-and-fabio).